# Yii2.0 yiic command not working

Tags: php, yii2, yiic

Hi I am new to Yii framework development.

Yiic webapp not working, even when you run yiic on the commandline

I was following a tutorial on-line but I got stuck because the yiic command is not recognised and I also noticed that the framework folder is not there.

I download Yii 2.0 archive from the Yii home website and extracted it to my Webroot folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `yiic` from **Yii 1.x**, you can use [Gii Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-gii-index.html) of **Yii 2**.

> `http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=gii`

It provides the same code generators:

- Model Generator
- CRUD Generator
- Controller Generator
- Form Generator
- Module Generator
- Extension Generator