# Where is the yiic command?

Tags: php, yii, yii2-user

I downloaded `yii` framework (both basic and advanced) from http://www.yiiframework.com/download/. But I could not find `yiic` command after extracting the zip file. I need to use this command to create migrate file for databases. I wonder where yiic is located? Where can I download this command?

Below is the content of the `yii`. I didn't find `yiic` command.

[image]

Comment: This is the bootstrap script for running yiic on Unix/Linux. You can find this file path in your Framework folder i.e `framework/yiic.php`

Comment: I have put the content of the yii in my post and I didn't find yiic.php file.

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232665/yii2-0-yiic-command-not-working)

Comment: @dod29 I just followed the instruction to create a new basic project. still there is no yiic command inside.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in yii2.0 there is no yiic command any more. Instead I should use yii migrate/create to create a migrate class.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will find all yiic files in below folder  structure
for yii1.1
yii->framework->

Answer (score 0):

On your command line, navigate to the advanced folder and run

```
php init
```

This will create setup your environment and create `yiic.php` and other files.